# When duplicating a Wordpress page, it breaks and looks different

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I tried duplicating a page in Wordpress in order to translate it for local users in different countries, but for some reason, even though it's the exact same page (it even looks the same inside wordpress preview) it just breaks and looks different (seems like a css problem of some sort, probably?)

The "nice" website is: 
www.blaqkdesign.com/?noredirect=true

The one i'm having problem with:
www.blaqkdesign.com/mx/?noredirect=true

Side note: "noredirect" is the command used in order to bypass IP redirection

Any ideas on what could be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the second one missing of **themify-builder-*4534*-generated.css?ver=17.09.19.04.52.54**, it should be named **themify-builder-*2534*-generated.css?ver=17.09.19.04.52.54**

Difference is **4534** should be **2543**, please try to change if possible.

Comment: I found out those numbers are the Page ID, so they need to be different in order to display the custom content. Now the question is, why is it breaking just because they have different page ID's?

Comment: That I understand, but the file name with 4534 is not found that may cause errors

Comment: For some reason, I found out those css files were supposed to be generated automatically, but they didn't. So I duplicated the first one, replacing the number "2543" to "4534" and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much for spotting the problem!